# Not able to create collection in solr after upgrading to 7.5 from 6.1

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud

I'm not able to create collection in solr after upgrading to solr 7.5 from solr 6.1

```
    {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":924},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","java.io.InvalidClassException"],
    "msg":"java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrResponse; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3945300637328478755, local class serialVersionUID = -7931100103360242645",
    "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrResponse; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3945300637328478755, local class serialVersionUID = -7931100103360242645\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrResponse.deserialize(SolrResponse.java:73)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.sendToOCPQueue(CollectionsHandler.java:364)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:272)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:246)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:734)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:715)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:496)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(Sessio
```

Comment: Im using 
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct jar versions for SolrJ?

Comment: yes solr 7.5.0 support java version 1.8+

Comment: That's not what I asked - Are you sure you're using all the correct jars for SolrJ? The exception happens in SolrJ, where the class versions are differing from what's expected. My initial guess is that this is either the internal classes differing between versions inside different jars, or the server handing out serialized class files that are newer than what the runtime can understand. Maybe you're still using the SolrJ (client) files from Solr 6.1 when access the 7.5 instance?

Comment: How to resolve this issue?